# How do I remove an image-system for avd file in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device, emulation

[image]

[image]

I want to remove the api 16 of jelly bean but there is not remove button how can I do that. image file is very big size file so I need don't many system image file

Comment: are you able to find system image in the installed list

Answer (score 74, accepted):

After selecting show hidden files option from windows explorer, go to the location where Android SDK is installed. Then open system-images folder. You will see a folder named as the api level same as jelly bean. Just remove that folder.

Comment: /Users/myeongsic/Library/Android/sdk/system-image path. is that right? only this one remove folder?

Comment: C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\system-images\ on Windows

Comment: On mac: /Users/<USER_NAME>/Library/Android/sdk

Comment: Delete Android system image with Tools / Android / SDK Manager is better.

Comment: %userprofile%\appdata\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images for current user profile on Windows

Answer (score 343):

- Go to Preferences / Appearance & Behaviour / System Settings / Android SDK
- Tick `Show package details` in the bottom right.
- Untick the version(s) of Android you want to uninstall and click
  `Ok`.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer, as it is the built-in way to manage the AVD images.

Comment: This should be the right answer. Let Android Studio SDK Manager handle the system image deletion instead of manually deleting system folders. It's the safe option and guaranteed to work. I recovered 50+ GB of disk space using this approach immediately on an iMac.

Comment: In version 3.5.3
`File` -> `Settings` -> `Appearance & Behavior` -> `System Settings` -> `Android SDK`

Comment: Tools > SDK Manager in 3.6.3

Comment: Thanks, this is the correct way to do it, not from the terminal.

Answer (score 31):

This is hidden now. to not delete your SDK along with the image. you need to

1. Tools->SDK manager
2. Select `show package details`,
3. then select the relevant system image only, leaving in your sdk

[image]

Answer (score 18):

For **Mac** users:

```
rm -r ~/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-XX
```

Comment: Thank you. From above suggestion, I just select image in folder by:

`open Library/Android/sdk/system-images/`

then delete desired image.

Answer (score 3):

The Process is relatively simple and is as follows:

1. Select the image from Android SDK Manager
2. Remove the unnecessary system image by selecting the image and then clicking Delete package.
3. Install your image of choice.

Comment: sorry I don't understand. look at second image. there was already "not install"

Comment: check if the same image is listed among Extras. Once, that happened to me.

Comment: check if intel x86 atom system image is listed in Extras

Answer (score 3):

File -> Settings-> SDK
1. Check 'Show Package Details'
2. Uncheck the System Image you want to Delete
3. Click 'OK' and will Delete ARM Images.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdwMn.png)

Answer (score 3):

For Android Studio Giraffe, using the new Android Studio ui

1. Go to Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> Android SDK
2. Tick Show package details in the bottom right.
3. Untick the version(s) of Android you want to uninstall and click Ok.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For Mac users is the same path
**Users > YourUserName > Library > Android > sdk > system-images**

Answer (score 0):

**CLI solution for Linux/Mac users:**

1. List all installed packages:

```bash
sdkmanager --list

Installed packages:
  Path                                    | Version | Description                    | Location
  -------                                 | ------- | -------                        | -------
  cmdline-tools;latest                    | 11.0.0  | PLACEHOLDER                    | cmdline-tools/latest
  emulator                                | 29.3.4  | PLACEHOLDER                    | emulator
  patcher;v4                              | 1       | SDK Patch Applier v4           | patcher/v4
  platform-tools                          | 34.0.4  | PLACEHOLDER                    | platform-tools
  platforms;android-27                    | 3       | Android SDK Platform 27, rev 3 | platforms/android-27
  system-images;android-27;default;x86_64 | 1       | Intel x86_64 Atom System Image | system-images/android-27/default/x86_64
```

2. Remove the desired packages, e.g.:

```bash
sudo sdkmanager --uninstall "system-images;android-27;default;x86_64
```

---

As a side note, there may be more than a single `sdkmanager` in the system, e.g., under:

- `/usr/bin/sdkmanager`, and
- `/opt/android-sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager`

Depending on which `sdkmanager` you use, you may see different packages!